# How to resend emails via Amazon SES which didn't go because of rate limiting

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses, rate-limiting

I am using Amazon SES to send bulk emails via a cron job. My application is processing around 40-50 emails per second, however I am only allowed to send 22 emails via SES.
[image]

If I send more than 22 emails, I run into below error -

```
com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceException: Maximum sending rate exceeded. 
(Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Throttling; 
Request ID: 5xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx8a4; Proxy: null)
```

I understand that to avoid it in future I will have to handle it gracefully in my code by using down-scaling, exponential backoff, etc as mentioned in this [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-handle-a-throttling-maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-error/).

However, I wanted to know if there is any way to re-send the emails(sent in past) which didn't go through because of rate-limiting.
I can see requestId along with the error. Does SES log it somewhere and provide any resend mechanism?

Even if I can get the list of emails which didn't go through, it will be helpful.

Comment: I'd look to change your architecture a bit and put the messages in an SQS queue.  Have a Lambda or other process pull them off the queue and try to send.  If the send fails then the message should not be removed from the queue and will be visible again after the visibility timeout.  This would allow for bursts of messages to eventually go out.  The only possible issue is if the messages are very large as SQS can only handle 256K.  In that case you may need to leverage S3 also.

Comment: I can implement a lot of mechanisms going forward. But I have some emails which didn't go out. So I am looking if I can find some way to resend them.

Comment: There isn't some database of unsent mail somewhere that AWS is keeping for you. The error code tells your code it can't be sent. After that it's up to you to save it.

Answer (score 1):

If your request was rejected by SES for whatever reason, it didn't even enter the pipeline, so it's not stored anywhere on AWS.

Even if it did, SES doesn't log message metadata out of the box. They have a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-log-amazon-ses-details-using-amazon-cloudwatch/) addressing just that:

> Currently SES provides various metrics like number of sends, reject etc. but there is no direct way to log information like From email identity, recipient email identity, Subject, timestamp, source IP address, messageId etc. when sending emails.

, in which they recommend building a custom solution involving SNS and Lambda to implement detailed logging of SES jobs.

It is a problem with lots of services, so one low-code solution I like to implement is proxying these calls through API Gateway and enabling Cloud Watch logs on the gateway level. It does slightly inflate your AWS bill, but it offers more visibility for what goes in and out AWS services.

As a side bonus, it lowers the coupling with AWS for the applications which are not too deeply integrated, because the AWS Gateway can be set up to only use an access key, so the HTTP client becomes the only dependency.

I understand it's not exactly helping you now, but I'll just leave it here for the future visitors.

Comment: This blog post is about messages SES did accept, so it doesn't really address the issue at hand, but your first sentence is correct — when messages are throttled, the service never sees them.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: thank you for pointing that out. I was rewriting the post and the crucial part got edited out.